# deploy lambda to s3 bucket folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Here is the command to deploy the lambda:

```
$ sam package --template-file sam.yaml --s3-bucket mybucket --output-template-file packaged.yaml
```

But can I specify a bucket prefix? so it gets deployed to subfolder instead of root of bucket?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can provide the bucket prefix using `--s3-prefix` parameter

`$ sam package --template-file sam.yaml --s3-bucket mybucket --s3-prefix path/to/file --output-template-file packaged.yaml`

Under the hood `sam` is calling `aws` command and all the options listed  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) are valid.

Comment: ahhhhh cool that makes sense. Is there a doc explaining exactly what cli calls sam is makes? like a mapping between them?

Comment: Couldn't find a sam  specific doc. This is the sam clie repo readme has decent amount of information https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local